How to show variable value in dart closure when debug Flutter code
When i debug my Flutter code in Android Studio, I found the variable value not show when i hover on variable code.
I try to use "Evaluate expression" that the debugger in AndroidStudio,  i input "this" and press enter,  show "result=-1002162400" in below form.
so I want to show the variable value in closure when debugging, someone help me?
click and show gif

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
